# Unable to define a click event on a href tag

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a click event for an anchor tag in my tampermonkey script.

```
var contentTag = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
var fileContents = contentTag.innerHTML;

contentTag.innerHTML = "";

var lines = fileContents.split("\n");
window.alert("Number of lines:"+lines.length);


for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
if(i!==15)
 contentTag.innerHTML+=(lines[i]+"<br>");
else {
    contentTag.innerHTML+=("<a id=link1>Click me</a>");
    var link = document.getElementById('link1');
    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.alert('I am clicked');
    }, false);
}
}
```

The alert message never gets triggered when I click on the link in the page dispalyed, even though I have a a click event listener defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the way you're adding HTML, you're reappending the link when you do this in the next iteration.

```
link.innerHTML += something
```

So the event handler is lost, and you can actually [**prove that**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3z3S/2/) by adding the event handler to the last element instead.
If you do it the proper way, creating elements and appending them, it works fine

```
var contentTag = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
var fileContents = contentTag.innerHTML;

contentTag.innerHTML = "";
var lines = fileContents.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i !== 15) {
        var txt = document.createTextNode(lines[i] || ''),
            br  = document.createElement('br');
        contentTag.appendChild(txt);
        contentTag.appendChild(br);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.id = 'link1';
        link.innerHTML = 'Click me';
        link.addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert('clicked')
        }, false);

        contentTag.appendChild(link)

    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3z3S/1/)

Comment: this works on fiddle. but it doesn't on my tampermonkey script

Comment: I have no idea how tampermonkey works, but this should work anywhere ?

Comment: This *does* work in Tampermonkey.  But, you should change the `"div"` to `"pre"` to match the OP's code and your fiddle.

Comment: did a double check. it does work on tampermonkey. must have missed out on something yesterday. thanks. But one more thing. in the link.addEventListener part, instead of defining a function as the second argument there, if I try to refer a function that has been defined outside the for loop, the function is not getting invoked. Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 0):

Shoud be `contentTag.innerHTML+=("<a id='link1'>Click me</a>");`

Comment: i am appending to innerHTML, so i have to put everything in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var contentTag = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
var fileContents = contentTag.innerHTML;

contentTag.innerHTML = "";

var lines = fileContents.split("\n");
window.alert("Number of lines:"+lines.length);

for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
if(i!==15)
 contentTag.innerHTML+=(lines[i]+"<br>");
else {
    contentTag.innerHTML+=("<a id=link"+i+">Click me</a>");
    var link = document.getElementById('link'+i);
    var att=document.createAttribute('onclick');
    att.value="alert('Clicked !')";
    link.setAttributeNode(att);
}
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmJ38/

Comment: This will not work from a userscript the moment the `alert` is changed to any practical JS.  The rule to never use `onclick` goes triple for userscripts.